# Difficulties with .scale method with Canvas when using tkinter with python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to load a .gif image into a canvas. Once loaded the picture is to be resized using the .scale method on the canvas. The image reloads but does not resize.

I am using python 3.6. I tried it in python 2.7 with the same result although on the full implementation rather that the simplified code shown below.

```
import tkinter as tk

f = "C:\Fanny Poer.gif"

root = tk.Tk() 

dis = tk.Canvas(root) 

dis.grid() 

new_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=f) 

id = dis.create_image(500, 500, image = new_image) 

dis.scale(id, 0, 0, .1, .1) 

root.mainloop()
```

The image loads but does not resize. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That simply isn't what `Canvas.scale()` does - it *only* affects coordinates, not any other details of the object.  (For example, scaling a line changes its endpoints, but not its width.)  You need to do your resizing on the `PhotoImage` object itself - I think `new_image = new_image.subsample(10)` would do the job.  (If you need a better quality scaling than that, or one that isn't an integer ratio, use the PIL/Pillow library to do it.)

Answer (score 0):

> Once loaded the picture is to be resized using the .scale method on the canvas.

You can't do that with the `scale` method. That method only affects the coordinates of an object. It won't resize an image.

To resize an image you can use the `subsample` and `zoom` methods on the `PhotoImage` instance, or you can use some other library (eg: [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) to resize the image.

Comment: I was using the description found in https://nnc3.com/mags/Perl3/tk/ch09_19.htm The subsample method does not work with PhotoImage.  I think that your suggestion of using the PIL/Pillow library is a good  one. I will work on this.

Comment: @JerryRadcliffe: that page isn't 100% correct. I don't know what you mean about the subsample method not working. It definitely works when used properly.